# Is it possible to restart tunnels with a control master sshsession?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I've got a bunch of machines that I create tunnels to using the a config file similar to the following:

```
Host mygizmo-tun143
  HostName 1.2.177.16
  HostKeyAlias [1.2.177.16]:6000
  User tunneluser
  Port 6000
  ServerAliveInterval 15
  ServerAliveCountMax 4
  Tunnel point-to-point
  TunnelDevice 143:0
  IdentityFile /home/tunnels/.ssh/id_dsa
  UserKnownHostsFile /home/tunnels/.ssh/known_hosts
  ConnectTimeout 10
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath /var/sshsessions/mygizmo-tun143
  ControlPersist yes
```

and I start the tunnel with the following script:

```
/bin/tunctl -u $USER -t $LOCAL_INTERFACE 
/bin/ip link set $LOCAL_INTERFACE down 
/bin/ip addr add $LOCAL_ADDRESS/30 peer $PEER_ADDRESS dev $LOCAL_INTERFACE 
/bin/ip link set $LOCAL_INTERFACE mtu 1300 
/bin/ip link set $LOCAL_INTERFACE up  

/usr/bin/ssh -n -T -F "$SSH_CONFIG_PATH" "$SSH_TUNNEL_HOST" "sudo        /opt/sbin/iproutetunnelsetup $REMOTE_INTERFACE $PEER_ADDRESS $LOCAL_ADDRESS" &
```

(the variables in that script aren't that important. The iproutetunnelsetup script does a similar thing on the peer and makes sure that interface is started)

This all works swimmingly, until there is a break in connection that screws up the tunnel interface, but leaves the ssh session hung open.

Outside of pinging the interface or counting packets, is there a way to know for sure that a point-to-point tunnel purported by ssh to work is really functioning.  I had thought (hoped) that tunnels would work like port forwards and just get tacked on to the existing instance, but it seems like you can only have one tunnel per instance and there's no "-O Cancel" command for tunnels.

;tl;dr

Are there any commands I can run against an ssh instance that will stop a tunnel while keeping the ssh session open?